# ajax not clearing form on submit

Tags: ajax, yii

I have a form and want to submit through ajax. It posts but it doesn't clear form onclick success. I've also tried .done(function). I've also tried alert data on success and error (thinking must be error) but it doesn't alert anything either.

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
    'Comment',
    'review/ajaxComment',
        array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'success'=>'js:function(data){
           if(data.result==="success"){
              document.getElementById("review-form").reset();
              alert("this worked");
           }else{
              console.log(error)
           }
       }'
    )
)?>
```

form

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'review-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true),)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<div class="rating-row">
    <?php $this->Widget('CStarRating', array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'attribute'=> 'star',
            'minRating'=>.5 ,
            'maxRating'=>5 ,
            'starCount'=>5 ,
            'ratingStepSize'=>.5 
    ));?>
</div>

<div class="rating-row">
<label>Reviews</label>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'review'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'review'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your form html?

Comment: it's a pretty straight forward form.

Comment: What response do you get from the server?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Assign a class for all `textbox`, `textarea`, `Dropdown`. For example, `frm_inp_ctrl`

Then, do `$(".frm_inp_ctrl").val("");` in ajax `done()`

**Method 2:**

Do reset with form id as below.

```
 $("#review-form :input").val("");
```